# How to deal with CoreData save errors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, error-handling

Avoiding data loss is a critical issue in my application. So I need to save early and often to ensure minimal loss and immediate notification if anything goes wrong.

Unfortunately this results in a lot of `if (![context save:&error]) {` handling all over the place. To clean this up in a more centralised way I thought to implement an NSManagedObjectContext category with a method such as this:

```
- (BOOL)saveNotify:(NSError **)error
{
    NSError *saveError;
    if (![self save:&saveError]) {

        NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"error" : saveError};

        [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter postNotificationName:NSManagedObjectContextSaveErrorNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];

        if (error != NULL) *error = saveError;

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Now I can listen for the notification in a more general way and throw up an alert to the user if the save has failed for some reason.

Is this a good approach or is there a better way to deal with this?

A secondary issue is what to actually do when this does occur. Asking the user to exit the app and restart is a bit convoluted these days as they need to close the app through the task switcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That'll work for notifying users of save errors. But there are a couple of things to keep in mind:

1. The message in `saveError` may not be comprehensible to users. You probably shouldn't present it. Instead, look at the error code and domain and try to present something that makes more sense.
2. You'll need to try and work out potential errors and likely solutions. Telling users to force-quit the app is unlikely to help if, for example, the persistent store has become corrupted or if the device is out of space. **Most** save errors will be things that come up during development, if you're testing thoroughly. Things like validation failures or missing required values.